# Embedding Terracotta

Tags: terracotta

I was hoping to configure Quartz to use Terracotta and the cluster would be built up ad-hoc when my servlet containers started up. All documentation I've seen seems to require the Terracotta cluster to be started up before hand as a separate service.

Is there a way to build the Terracotta cluster into my web application so I don't need to manage multiple services?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Terracotta clustering by default requires at least one separate server to be running. All testing of Terracotta assumes that the server is running alone in the JVM.

So no, there is no support for what you want to do out of the box.